# How to get all children of an element in python using selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

How can I turn this JavaScript into Python to get all child elements from the parent?

This script gets all the elements from the google.com site via console

```
e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children

for (let i = 0; i < e.length;i++){
    console.log(e[i].tagName)
}
```

In python I tried to do this, but I can't

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\geck\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.google.com.br/')
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
childrens = body.childrens

for i in childrens:
    print(i.tagName)

driver.quit()
```

Commands used to install packages:

```
pip install pandas
pip install bs4
pip install selenium
pip install requests
```

How can I get the element names from a body tag in python?

Comment: If you want to execute java script in python with selenium, you can use this: driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children")

Comment: it's `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name` plural

Comment: @QualityMatters Interesting, can I show the tag name? Using execute_script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `body.find_elements_by_xpath("./child::*")` to get all the child elements in body as `WebElement` object and then get their tag name by accessing the `tag_name` attribute

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\geck\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.google.com.br/')
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
childrens = body.find_elements_by_xpath("./child::*")

for i in childrens:
    print(i.tag_name)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

To turn this [*JavaScript*](https://www.javascript.com/) into *Python* to get all child elements from the parent

```
e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children

for (let i = 0; i < e.length;i++){
    console.log(e[i].tagName)
}
```

in a simple and crispy way you just need to pass the *JavaScript* within `execute_script()` as follows:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com.br/")
driver.execute_script("""
    e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children
    for (let i = 0; i < e.length;i++){
    console.log(e[i].tagName)
}
""")
```

Snapshot of the Console:

[image: JavaScript]

Comment: _gets all the elements from the google.com site via **console**_: As per your question I thought you wanted the output on the console :)